# How to communicate with frame page.xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

- I'm coding a windows form using WPF, XAML, C#.
- I have a Frame object created in MainWindow.xaml, and the frame
  points to Login.xaml.
- Login.xaml handles a login operation for a user and the logic for
  this is stored in Login.xaml.cs.

How can I get Login.xaml to communicate with the code in MainWindow.xaml.cs so that it can change the frame once a user logs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communicate through view models using events. Or look for some [event aggregator](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation) to eliminate coupling between the view models.

`MainWindowViewModel` will instantiate `LoginViewModel`, display the `Login` control and register an event OnLoggedIn and on successful login it will [switch to another frame/screen](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager).